# firebase custom domain not working with www. prefix?

Tags: reactjs, hosting

I am new to firebase hosting. i recently launched my react app with a custom domain using firebase. after connecting the domain, i can enter it properly if i use the domain adress without add www. prefix at the beginning.

when tryong to enter the page with www. the page results in an unsevure connection, and not showing my project.

i have added a custom record with a host of www type A and value provided by firebase, according to the menu provided here,

i tried aadding DNS records. it made the connection secure, but resulted in a site not found message